# mysql procedure CONCAT error

Tags: mysql

I want copy data to table from another table with  current month

This sql is ok
`SELECT * FROM aqi_hour where  DATE_FORMAT( date, '%Y%m' ) =  DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) ,'%Y%m' )`

---

But this is not ok , execute CALL porcedureName()
`create procedure porcedureName () 
begin 
    SET @sqlstr = CONCAT(' CREATE TABLE aqi_hour_',DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m') ,' SELECT * FROM aqi_hour where ', DATE_FORMAT( date, '%Y%m' ) ,'=', DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) , '%Y%m' ));
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sqlstr ;
        EXECUTE stmt1 ; 
end`

Error message : [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SET @`sqlstr` := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE aqi_hour_', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m'),
                        ' SELECT *
                          FROM aqi_hour
                          WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, \'%Y%m\') =
                                DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() , \'%Y%m\')
                        ');
```